# QProcess inside QtConcurrent::mapped - no slots called

Tags: qt, concurrency, timer, process

The following code works - "echo" program is called for "abc" and "def",
the results are collected and printed.

If timer delay is set to 0, it stops working.

"echo" is called, even the readLine (if called) would return the right content,
but "finished" slot is never called. process.state() shows that the process is still running.

Why?

```
QFuture<QString> tfuture;
QFutureWatcher<QString> twatcher;

QString ftest(QString a){
    QProcess process;
    QEventLoop loop;
    QObject::connect(&process, &QProcess::finished, [&](int exit_code) {
        qDebug() << "OK " << a << " " << exit_code;
        loop.exit(0);
    });
    QTimer::singleShot(1, [&] {
        qDebug() << "STARTING " << a;
        process.start("echo", {{"ECHO ", a}});
    });
    loop.exec();
    return process.readLine();
};

void tfinished() {
    QList<QString> result = twatcher.future().results();
    qDebug() << "finished " << result;
}

...
QStringList params = {{"abc", "def"}};
tfuture = QtConcurrent::mapped(params, ftest);
connect(&twatcher, &QFutureWatcher<QString>::finished, this, &tfinished);
twatcher.setFuture(tfuture);
```

Comment: Not answering the question but - why the hell do you need to wrap a QProcess call into a separate thread at all? QProcess is async so no need to add another async layer on top...

Comment: It's a part of a longer function with lots of processing in each thread. Anyway, I want to know what is wrong. Don't like random behavior - not sure if I can rely on Qt or rather use boost and std.